# about get value from sqlite

Tags: objective-c, copy, sqlite

Code Sample:

```
NSString *str= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)];
Test *t=[[Test alloc] init];
t.str=[str copy]; // why use "copy" here?
[str release];
```

Comment: Please edit the code sample to make it readable. Put four spaces at the beginning of each line to format it as text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be bad coding, for two reasons. Since `str` is being discarded, you might as well assign it, rather than a copy, to `t.str`. Second, and more importantly, setters should take care of retaining or copying data.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
NSString *str= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)];
Test *t=[[Test alloc] init];
t.str=str; // No point copying to release original.
```

Comment: The release is most likely correct, for the particular code block is probably done with `str`.

Comment: @outis - while the `release` was correct in order to balance the `retain` implied by `copy`, the use of `copy` itself is unnecessary (as you accurately describe in your answer)

Comment: @Dave: You're right; I overlooked the fact that str is autoreleased.